# How to increase no of mapper in the Sqoop job

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, amazon-emr, sqoop2

I am trying to load data from S3 to RDS using Sqoop .
I have approx 35 GB gzip files in 70 different file .

Here is my command which i run to do that

```
sqoop export 
 --connect jdbc:mysql://a205067-pppp-ec2rds.abcd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/tprdb 
 --username user 
 --password password 
 --table DnB_WB_UniverseMaster 
 --export-dir s3://pppp-sukesh/FullFiles/ 
 --fields-terminated-by  '|' 
 --num-mappers 500 
 --direct 
 --default-character-set=latin1
```

`dunsnumber` is my primary key

The issue is export is very very slow and the no of mapper i can see is only 4 .

What opymization i can do here in order to make load faster .

Also i have EMR cluster with `10 m4.large`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use only one dash with `m` argument: `-m 20` or `--num-mappers 20`.

Comment: No still same no of mappers i am getting ...Anything that needs to be done from RDS side ?

Comment: Try to move `-- --default-character-set=latin1` to the end of command since the Sqoop CLI has the following structure: `sqoop TOOL PROPERTY_ARGS SQOOP_ARGS [-- EXTRA_ARGS]`

Comment: Yes it increases your suggestion is working ..But  i have given 500 mapper but i can see only 70 ..Also the time it is taking is same ...I have updated my question with the command i am trying ...

Comment: The parameter `--num-mappers` serves as a hint. In most cases, you will get the specified number of mappers, but it’s not guaranteed. If your data set is very small, Sqoop might resort to using a smaller number of mappers. For example, if you’re transferring only 4 rows yet set `--num-mappers` to 10 mappers, only 4 mappers will be used, as the other 6 mappers would not have any data to transfer.